# How load sharing can be done in AC mains and inverter?

Tags: power, power-electronics, inverter, mains, esp8266

I want to do load sharing in between ac mains and inverter? But How it can be done, I have no idea.

In the above line, many experts will not understand the question, so I am just explaining a simple example below:-

Suppose we need to drive a load of 10 kW (load can anything or mostly all the loads are combined to form the 10 kW) in our household. But in my area, the utility sector provides only 5 kW to drive the load. but if I go above beyond this we need to pay for this extra. But in my home, I have an inverter (inverter can be any type may be a solar or conventional system with battery) which is rated of 6 kW, so why we will purchase extra energy from the utility sector if we have an inverter. so what we will do we want to share the power or bypass the load, in simple terms if we set the limit of ac mains to 4 kW and after beyond going to 4 kW my power will be shared by the inverter which will 6 kW.

Now this power distribution will be done by the microcontroller and some hardware apparatus (e.g.IC's, gates).

So I explain everything that I need to do.
SO first I thing I need to do share the power, mean to say how I can minimize the power transfer from the grid, and allows maximum power from the inverter well grid is still ON, no power cut.

I request to all please kindly share me some basic ideas on this.
Recommend me any book/reference paper for this, please? I apologize for not posting any pictures or any code. because this is a practical question that I need to do.

Comment: Can the output frequency of your inverter be unambiguously phase-locked to the incoming mains AC? If not then seperate your loads and share power by using seperate circuits.

Comment: sir, I didn't get it. what you are trying to say?

Comment: sir, I would be happy please share some topics on them where I can read.

Comment: Well, I thought I was clear and reading what I said once more, it appears that I am. Maybe you need to read up on things like this? This site isn't about helping you find reading material; it's about questions and answers.

Comment: sir, can you brief once more time, seriously I am not getting anything.please mention some important topics on that.

Comment: It's very basic what I said so if you don't understand it you are probably not ready to do this design. This is a question and answer site and not about recommending on requests or free-circuits on demand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113516/discussion-between-arijeet-roy-and-andy-aka).

Comment: It's very basic what I said so if you don't understand it you are probably not ready to do this design. This is a question and answer site and not about recommending on requests or free-circuits on demand. –

Comment: It's very basic what I said so if you don't understand it you are probably not ready to do this design. This is a question and answer site and not about recommending requests or free-circuits on demand. – As I said before didn't get your words what you have described above. it is not necessary that what you will write and people will understand. yes, my basics were not clear about the topic that's why posted here on this platform but I am ready to do the learn the concepts.

Comment: What you are asking for is too broad and not suitable for this site. If you wish to understand the fundamentals of connecting an inverter with incoming AC you should do some research because it's a big subject and fraught with legislation red-tape too.

Comment: with due to all respect sir, maybe you don't know about this topic but others will know about the topic. I guess you will welcome other expertise to give a review on the same.

Comment: **What you are asking for is too broad and not suitable for this site** sir I need to ask you why you preventing or refusing this type of question .it is because you don't know about the topic and you can decide which question is acceptable or not. please don't give a useless review if you don't about the topic. because other experts will distract and will not give suggestions, thanks.

Comment: I agree, there's a dangerous possibility that some little-hitler (potentially "me" as seen by "you") might be making a noise and putting other engineers off from making a decent answer and therefore thwarting you from gaining knowledge. "I" might be potentially doing it for several underhand reasons such as bigotry or racism or that the vowel-to-consonant ratio in your name is too high. So, what I recommend is that you report my comments to site moderators and let them decide. They'll probably delete this comment of course but they might also explain to you why I'm being reasonable.

Comment: sir, I don't have a lot of time to do such things. you are very senior to me but I didn't like your reviews it doesn't mean you can say anything to me.and surely you are reasonable in your topics but it doesn't mean that if you don't know on the topic, so no one can review on the topic.

Comment: It takes just 20 seconds to flag a comment - look for the grey flag symbol next to my comment and please do report me if you think I need to be reported. After flagging you have one of four tick-box options and you can also leave a few words. Maybe I should do this for you?

Comment: sir, I already mess with my work. I don't care about these things.

Comment: Do you want site moderators to look into what you are alleging?

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do this is:

- Use a grid-tie inverter. This is one that synchronises the AC from the inverter with the AC on the mains.
- The grid tie inverter will have safety features to ensure that if mains fails that the inverter will not put power out on the grid and possibly electrocute a lineman.
- Now you have two feeds into your house. The loads will consume all the available power from the inverter and the mains will make up the rest.

If your inverter is not a grid-tie type then you cannot use it in this manner. You will usually have to notify the utility company that you wish to do this and may be subject to inspection to ensure that you comply with local regulations.

Note, I have given some terminology here to get you started on your own research. I will not be designing a system for you or having a conversation about it.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable views on this. but I need to search more about it.

Comment: could you recommend me any book/reference paper for this, please?

Comment: Please read my last paragraph again.

Comment: Note, I have given some terminology here to get you started on your own research. I will not be designing a system for you or having a conversation about it. Thank you, sir